# sed explanation so I can recreate a bit of code?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, wget, gnome-terminal

Can someone please explain the following sed command?

```
title=$(wget -q -O - https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=$ID | sed -n 's/^.*<title>\(.*\) on Twitter<.title>.*$/\1/p')
printf "%s\n" "$title"
```

I tried (and failed terribly) to recreate it because I thought I understood what was going on in the code. So I wrote (well, more modded) it to be the following:

```
data-user-id=$(wget -q -O - https://twitter.com/$Username | sed -n 's/^.*"data-user-id">\([^<]*\)<.*$/\1/p')
printf "%s\n" "$data-user-id"
```

Obviously it errored because the syntax is wrong or something. But I'm trying to understand what is going on so I can make my own variant of it.

P.S. I can't just use the API for this due to how everything needs to be configured.

Comment: I think what you have missed is that sed works line by line. In the first example both the opening and the closing tags are on the same line, in your second example probably not. There are several tools designed to deal with html that are better fitted for this kind of tasks than sed or a text approach.

Comment: Okay, and yea data-user-id is stored as a variable and not a tag so yea it wouldnt work if that is what it is doing :-/ `<div class="js-account-summary account-summary js-actionable-user "data-user-id="2237761442" data-feedback-token="500" data-impression-id>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to this:

```
wget -q -O - https://twitter.com/"${Username}" | sed -n '/data-screen-name=.'"${Username}"'".*data-user-id=/I {s/^.*data-screen-name=.'"${Username}"'".*data-user-id="\([0-9]*\)".*$/\1/Ip;q}'

128700677
```

`data-user-id` is present in several lines, so it is needed to select a line where `data-screen-name=Username`

`sed` is using regular expression, there are 2 good tutorials to start with:

- [Regular Expressions](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html)
- [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

A different `sed` script with a different output:

```
Username="StackOverflow"
wget -q -O - https://twitter.com/"${Username}" | sed -n '/data-screen-name=.'"${Username}"'".*data-user-id=/I {p;q}'

data-screen-name="StackOverflow" data-name="Stack Overflow" data-user-id="128700677"
```

`-n` instructs `sed` to not print anything, except when `p` command is used.

`.` means any char.

`*` applies to the previous char in the regex and it means zero or any number of this char.

`.*` means zero or any number of any char.

`/data-screen-name=.'"${Username}"'".*data-user-id=/` select lines which contains `data-screen-name=` and any one char (`.`) and `StackOverflow` and `"` char and zero or any number of any char (`.*`) and `data-user-id=`.

`/I` means ignore case.

`{p;q}` are commands executed when above regex is true.
`p` prints the current line. 
`q` exits the `sed` script.

The first `sed` script at the top contains an additional `s/regex/replacement/` to clean up the line.

The additional elements used:

`^` means the start of the line.

`\( ... \)` are used to define a group.

`"\([0-9]*\)"` is a group made of only digits, surrended with 2 `"` which are not part of the group. It is the first group found in the regex, so it can be referenced in the replacement part with `\1`.

Comment: It doesn't give me any output, i just tried outputting it to a file as well and it stays blank.

Comment: username is case insensitive when used with URL but data-screen-name is case sensitive. The answer still needs to be completed.

Comment: @Matt the answer had been updated. Use the first sed command. The second is just here to explain in detail and show one line of the file downloaded with wget.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the explenation...it doesnt give a reply to only one that I have tried but all the rest go through. Thank you!

Comment: Would you be willing to update this so that it would search for `\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/` and echoes the digits after that? A lot of these accounts are putting their security on private. I tried to do it myself but i couldnt figure it out. I made a new question but nobody knows how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the title of the page is "foo on Twitter", it extracts "foo" from it.

But use [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) instead, since it allows you to specify XPath to extract the data instead of having to poke around with regular expressions.

Comment: Sadly I need this to be in pure bash without extra addons included or else I would have used anything to make it easier on myself.

Comment: Well, technically neither wget nor sed are pure bash, so take that as you will.

Comment: Okay, sorry. without installing extra software besides what is on the .iso when you get a new debian based image.